# Converter JSON de API graphql para array

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Eu tenho uma conexão de pesquisa para uma **API graphql**, essa pesquisa retorna um **JSON**, onde eu o armazeno em `content` e depois o transformo em array, mas esse array não está mostrando os valores contidos nele, mantém os valores em `[array]`, em vez de mostrar via `console.log()`

**Script**

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

let queryAPI = {

    "query": `{
                squads {
                    name
                        cards(includedOnKanban: true, closed: false, archived: false, cancelled: false, updatedSince: \"2020-01-01T00:00:00-0300\") {
                            identifier
                            title
                            description
                            status
                            priority

                            assignees {
                                fullname
                                email
                              }

                        }
                    }
            }`

};

(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://www.bluesight.io/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Bluesight-API-Token': 'token-here'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(queryAPI)
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  //console.log(JSON.stringify(content.data));

  var result = [];

  for(var i in content)
      result.push([i, content[i]]);
      console.log(content[i])

})();
```

**JSON String example:**

> {
>       "data": {
>           "squads": [
>               {
>                   "name": "SUPPORT IT",
>                   "cards": [
>                       {
>                           "identifier": "06x38y",
>                           "title": "ALL - Validate data,
>                           "description": "review database.",
>                           "status": null,
>                           "priority": "medium",
>                           "assignees": [
>                               {
>                                   "fullname": "Carlos",
>                                   "email": "carlos@br.it.com",
>                               }
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   ]
>               }
>           ]
>       } }

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  squads: [ { name: 'SUPPORT IT', cards: [Array] } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O console.log() pode não ser muito especifico se você não possar uma array exatamente,
basicamente, faça:

```
console.log(content[i]["squads"][0]["cards"]); //Index 0 como exemplo, você pode colocar um 2° for
```

E ele mostrará na tela a array com os seus dados

Comment: opaaa, era msm minha dúvida, mt obg!!